# Find location corresponds to specific range in colorbar in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, colorbar

Consider I have a colorbar from 0 to 1 in Matlab. I would like to know  how I can find what locations in image( pixel values) correspond to the range from 0.7 to 0.8 in the colorbar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data goes from `min(data)` to `max(data)` and you didnt manually set up the colorbar limits, then a position in the colorbar is calculated by:

```
colorbarpos= (p-min(data))/(max(data)-min(data))
```

therefore

```
p=colorbarpos*(max(data)-min(data))+min(data)
```

as Suggested by @Divakar you may want this:

```
[r,c] = ind2sub(size(data),find(data>=0.7 & data<=0.8))
```

Comment: so here p corresponds to 0.7 and 0.8 ?

Comment: p corresponds to value "colorbarpos". colorbarpos=0.7 -> p07 ;

Comment: I tried this but this one gives me the fraction number.I am looking for a location in a image that corresponds to 0.7-0.8 range in colorbar meaning that 0.7 corresponds to 100th elements of data.

Comment: I really dont get what you are asking. If you want the data corresponding to that fraction, you need to get p07 and p08 values and the data that is in that part can be get by data((data<p08)&&(data>p07)). Thats what you mean? If not, please edit your aswer with a more specific question.

Comment: @user59419 Assuming `data` to be the 2D indexed image data, maybe you are looking for this - `[r,c] = ind2sub(size(data),find(data>=0.7 & data<=0.8))`. In X-Y coordinates when on a figure window, this would
correspond to `X = c,Y = r`.

Comment: Exactly that's what I meant. Thanks to both of you Ander and Divakar.

Comment: @AnderBiguri Since comments get deleted, it would be nicer I guess to incorporate the stuffs that worked to solve OP into the solution.